# How to delete the text in a Text without getting rid of the tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter, tags

Hello I've been using:

```
self.output_box.config(state=NORMAL)
self.output_box.delete("1.0", END)
self.output_box.insert(INSERT, output)
self.output_box.config(state=DISABLED)
```

To delete all the text in a Text, output_box, not a string but a widget from TKinter and place the new text, output, within the Text. However in using the .delete method to clear all the text I also delete all the tags that Text has. I've been looking to clear the text from the Text without clearing the Tags of Text but haven't found what I'm looking for. I'm new to this whole Tkinter thing so I'm not sure if my method is the best any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with Tkinter, but is there a `setText(String)`? If so, you could always set the text to an empty string. (`setText("")`)

Comment: I've been looking for something like that but it seems that unlike Java's JTextarea TKinter's Text doesn't have that method.

Comment: Deleting the text _does not_ delete the tags in the widget. To remove tags you must explicitly call `tag_delete`.